# Hook a Javascript event to fire on another application OR suggestions

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

We have a web based jquery mobile app that records activity of a user. This app is long standing and in use at the moment, so re-writing the application is not an option unfortunatly.

The **problem** is that we are trying to get GPS location at certain points using the application.. But as it is running in an instance of chrome, the javascript will not record correctly when the phone is locked, or the chrome is minimised.

So to get around that we are writing an Ionic App with Cordova in order to get the GPS coordinates in the background, regardless of the state of the browser.

Currently, this is working great. The issue however is there are certain events in our javascript that require a specific 'type' associated to our GPS logging.

My question is: **How do I actually hook onto this javascript event in CHROME from the GPS background ionic/cordova application.**

**What we have tried so far:**

1. Finding the chrome localstorage via Ionic/Cordova and reading a value from that on a timer. 
   The issue with this is we can't find the location of the localstorage/cache. 
   From this question it says its here:

   /data/data/com.android.chrome/cache

but we can't find/access it from our ionic app or file browser on the android
https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/85998/android-google-chrome-browser-cache-location

2. We have also looked for ways to hook the javascript events to fire something inside the other application but we are having no luck there either..

Apologies for the long post.. Its hard to explain. If you have any suggestions on alternative methods to do this kind of cross-application event firing from Chrome to Ionic/Cordova I would be greatly interested to hear your oppinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this I created a 'stack' where I could push an object to an array that would be picked up by the cordova app using `executeScript` as follows:

In the inappbrowser site:

```
var stackName = stackN1
function addEventToStack(numid, type) {
    var stackRow = { 'numb': numid, 'type': type};
    var stack = localGet(stackName); //localstorage
    if (!stack)
        stack = StackInit();
    stack.push(stackRow);
    localStore(stackName, stack);
    console.log('Added to stack ', stack);
    return 'Row Added';
}
```

In the cordova application:

```
ref.executeScript(
            { 
                code: 'localStorage.getItem("stackN1")'
            }, 
            function(rdObj) { 
                  //Iterate and use rdObj here
    }
```